# How can I use switch type arguments for subroutines in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to call subroutines in Perl like:

```
sub temp {
  ---- some code -----
}
temp(-switchName, value1, --switchName2, value2)
```

Like I know Getopt::Long is there for command line switches type arguments.
So I want to know for subroutine type arguments.

Comment: You have accepted *none* of the answers to your questions in the past. Please work on correcting that.

Comment: Why do you need that?  Sorry if that comes off as rude, but I ask because the reason changes the answer.

Comment: As of the time of this writing, you edited your original question to a completely different one and now the answers make no sense. Please revert your question, and post your new one under a different question.

Comment: Given that the OP ignored the request to revert his question, I've done it for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of reasons why one might want to do that, but you didn't say so I'm going to have to speculate some.

Switches on the command line are useful because command line programs mix up options with a list of arguments and need some way of knowing the difference.  Thus the "things which start with - are not regular arguments" convention.

```
command --key value --key2 value2 file1 file2 file3
command file1 --key value file2 --key2 value2 file3
```

You can certainly do something similar with a subroutine, where it picks through its list of arguments looking for things that start with `--` and implying the next in the list is the associated value... but subroutines have better and easier ways to do it.

```
temp( ["file1", "file2", "file3"], { something => 1 } );
```

In this case the main list of arguments are passed in first as an array reference, and the options are passed in second in a hash reference.  There's no ambiguity.

```
sub temp {
    my($files, $options) = @_;

    print "Something!\n" if $options->{something};

    for my $file (@$files) {
        ...do something with $file...
    }
}
```

You can even take this one step further and pass in everything as an option.

```
temp( files => ["file1", "file2", "file3"], something => 1 );

sub temp {
    my %args = @_;

    print "Something!\n" if $args{something};

    for my $file (@{$args{files}}) {
        ...do something with $file...
    }
}
```

That's useful if it's not so clear what's an option and what's an argument.  Probably overkill for the "list of files with options" example here.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$options->{something}` being a hashref?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you can pass your arguments to a hash and use it to acces them. Like that:

```
sub temp {
  my %opts = @_;

  if ($opts{'-switch1'}) {
    # ... do something ...
  }

  ...
}

temp(-switch1 => 1);
# or
temp(-switch1, 1);
```

Comment: @user970553, if the code helped, the please check the "Accept" button next to it. This says "thanks" to the author and helps the next reader see which answer was correct.